# can we implement any methods inside interface in java

Tags: java, interface

```
interface temp
{
   public int add(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }
}
```

can we implement method like above in interface,
or we have to just define methods in interface.

Comment: @BackSlash: that thread is out of date. In the current versions of Java, it is possible to have implemented methods in interfaces, allbeit default methods.

Comment: @Stultuske Did you read the thread in question ? The accepted answer is all about that.

Comment: @AlexisC.: no doubt that's why they were going gung ho on Java 6

Comment: I agree the duplicate is a bit off, because it talks about static methods (default methods are only mentioned in passing). Either way, with Java 8, you have these two options now. Before that, you had neither.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html for further informations.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can in Java 8, using default methods

```
interface temp
{
   default public int add(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }
}
```

As mentioned by Thilo in the comments, Java 8 also added the possibility to have static methods in interfaces:

```
interface temp
{
   public static int add(int a,int b)
   {
      return a+b;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Since OP is asking about *any* method then answer is no because we can't implement this way methods from Object class like `equals` or `toString`.

Comment: Nitpicking response: OP was asking if we can implement *any* methods. Not *every* method.

Comment: But what happens if you provide a default for `toString` in your interface? Some compile error on the class that implements it (asking it to explicitly specify which `toString` it wants to inherit)?

Comment: @Thilo I think it is never used since the inherited `toString` from the parent class or `Object` always has precedence

Comment: Without any warning? That would be a pity/confusing. I kind of expect to get an error. What happens when you inherit the same default method from two interfaces?

Comment: @Thilo this gives a compiler error

Comment: @Thilo It indeed produces a compile error. Concerning your second point, if you inherit the same default method, you are forced to provide an implementation, either by explicitly delegates the call to one of the interface or by providing your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `java 8` then you can only define methods in interface.

```
 public interface temp {
     int add(int a,int b);
}
```

This is a new feature "default method in interface" introduced in `java 8`.